# Updating DDD Aggregates with Collections

Tags: c#, angular, rest, domain-driven-design

So, I've got an aggregate( Project ) that has a collection of entities (ProjectVariables) in it.  The variables do not have Ids on them because they have no identity outside of the Project Aggregate Root.

```
public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ProjectVariable> ProjectVariables { get; set; }

}


public class ProjectVariable
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<string> Scopes { get; set; }
}
```

The user interface for the project is an Angular web app.  A user visits the details for the project, and can add/remove/edit the project variables.  He can change the name.  No changes persist to the database until the user clicks save and the web app posts some json to the backend, which in turns passes it down to the domain.

In accordance to DDD, it's proper practice to have small, succinct methods on the Aggregate roots that make atomic changes to them.  Examples in this domain could be a method Project.AddProjectVariable(projectVariable).

In order to keep this practice, that means that the front end app needs to track changes and submit them something like this:

```
public class SaveProjectCommand
{
    public string NewName { get; set; }

    public List<ProjectVariable> AddedProjectVariables { get; set; }

    public List<ProjectVariable> RemovedProjectVariables { get; set; }

    public List<ProjectVariable> EditedProjectVariables { get; set; }
}
```

I suppose it's also possible to post the now edited Project, retrieve the original Project from the repo, and diff them, but that seems a little ridiculous.

This object would get translated into Service Layer methods, which would call methods on the Aggregate root to accomplish the intended behaviors.

So, here's where my questions come...

1. ProjectVariables have no Id.  They are transient objects.  If I need to remove them, as passed in from the UI tracking changes,  how do identify the ones that need to be removed on the Aggregate?  Again, they have no identification.  I could add surrogate Ids to the ProjectVariables entity, but that seems wrong and dirty.
2. Does change tracking in my UI seem like it's making the UI do too much?
3. Are there alternatives mechanisms?  One thought was to just replace all of the ProjectVariables in the Project Aggregate Root every time it's saved.  Wouldn't that have me adding a Project.ClearVariables() and the using Project.AddProjectVariable() to the replace them?  Project.ReplaceProjectVariables(List) seems to be very "CRUDish"
4. Am I missing something a key component?  It seems to me that DDD atomic methods don't mesh well with a pattern where you can make a number of different changes to an entity before committing it.

Answer (score 1):

> In accordance to DDD, it's proper practice to have small, succinct
>   methods on the Aggregate roots that make atomic changes to them.

I wouldn't phrase it that way. The methods should, as much as possible, reflect cohesive operations that have a domain meaning and correspond with a verb or noun in the ubiquitous language. But the state transitions that happen as a consequence are not necessarily small, they can change vast swaths of Aggregate data.

I agree that it is not always feasible though. Sometimes, you'll just want to change some entities field by field. If it happens too much, maybe it's time to consider changing from a rich domain model approach to a CRUD one.

> ProjectVariables have no Id. They are transient objects.

So they are probably [Value Objects](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) instead of Entities.

You usually don't modify Value Objects but replace them (especially if they're immutable). `Project.ReplaceProjectVariables(List)` or some equivalent is probably your best option here. I don't see it as being too CRUDish. Pure CRUD here would mean that you only have a setter on the `Variables` property and not even allowed to create a method and name it as you want.